# Is there any influence of time on Brahman?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, brahman, time

It is believed that the Supreme God is beyond the time. But [this](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/11/38/) verse from Srimad Bhagavatham says **Supreme God's one second (less than a second actually)** is equal to life span of Brahma.

> कालोऽयं द्विपरार्धाख्यो निमेष उपचर्यते
>   
> अव्याकृतस्यानन्तस्य ह्यनादेर्जगदात्मनः ॥ ३.११.३८ ॥
>   
>  Meaning: **The duration of the two parts of Brahmā’s life, as above mentioned, is calculated to be equal to one nimeṣa [less than a second] for the Supreme Personality of Godhead**, who is unchanging and unlimited and is the cause of all causes of the universe.

Is this verse defining Supreme God's time? or is there anything wrong with this verse? or I misunderstood it?

Comment: save us all time. what verse exactly are you quoting?????

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I have given the verse link (1st line).

Comment: It's made clear in the very next verse.

Comment: @Pandya I just checked but i didn't get ur point. U explain me how it's clear...

Comment: They just mean Krishna vs Brahmadeva. Don't look deeper it is as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

**Is there any influence of time on Brahman?**

No. By mentioning Brahma's entire life equal to less than a second, author actually wants to show infinite time.

[Chapter 5th of Kurma Purana](https://archive.org/stream/KurmaPurana.Vol.1/Kurma%20Purana.%20Vol.%201#page/n93/mode/1up/search/kurma+purana) says

> This Brahman is beginningless, endless, free from old age or decay and immortal. He is the Supreme Ruler because of his omnipresence, independence and his state of being the soul of all.

[Here](https://archive.org/stream/puran_kurma/Kurma#page/n23/mode/1up) is the Sanskrit shlokas and Hindi translation:

> [image]

It is also clear from [3.11.39 verse of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/11/39/):

> कालोऽयं परमाण्वादिर्द्विपरार्धान्त ईश्वरः
>
> नैवेशितुं प्रभुर्भूम्न ईश्वरो धाममानिनाम् ॥ ३.११.३९ ॥
>
> Eternal time is certainly the controller of different dimensions, from that of the atom up to the superdivisions of the duration of Brahmā’s life; but, nevertheless, **it (time) is controlled by the Supreme**. **Time can control only those who are body conscious**, even up to the Satyaloka or the other higher planets of the universe.

Also the source from where you have quoted the verse in your question has the following commentary:

> There is complete agreement between Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam and the Brahma-saṁhitā. Eternal time is never lost along with the life of Brahmā. It continues, but **it (time) has no ability to control the Supreme Personality of Godhead because the Lord is the controller of time**.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> 37. The period called *dvi-parārdha* is regarded as (a negligible period like) a wink of unmanifested, infinite beginingless Soul of the Universe.

Here 'nimesha' does not mean a moment. It means 'winking of an eye'
(Reference: sanskritdictionary.com).

So, it has to be taken in allegorical sense, otherwise it will contradict with the other parts of the scriptures like Srimad-Bhagavatam etc. A copy of proper translation by MLBD is enclosed as image.

'AvyAkrita' means the Supreme Brahman. (Reference: sanskritdictionary.com). Supreme Brahman is termed as 'Turiya' in Srimad-Bhagavatam (11/15/16). This sloka is quoted in Sri Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita (Adi, Second).

Mahaprabhu says in this context:

> turiya krishner nAhi mAyAr samvandha (CC, Adi, 2nd, sloka 86).

Time is caused by Maya. So, Krishna being Turiya is beyond Maya and hence beyond any measurement of time. His limitlessness is being implied by this allegory. Its comparable to the concept of epsilon in differential calculus branch of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

I am quoting any sources rather want to give a logical answer. Now time is an illusion(Maya), and Maya is inherent part of ब्रह्म, He is controller of Maya not otherwise. Thus, time becomes irrelevant when we talk about ब्रह्म .

And the quote stated is only used to describe how time scale is irrelevant.

Comment: A reference quote would be handy! BTW welcome to the site!!!